# Why does this create a StopIteration error?

Tags: python, generator

Why does this

```
a = (i for i in range(2))
b = a
c = a
for i in b:
    print("ok")
next(c)
```

result in this?

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-37-9c481bb09894> in <module>()
      54 for i in b:
      55   print("ok")
 ---> 56 next(c)

StopIteration:
```

I'm currently learning about generators in python. My goal here was to set up a as a generator, make b, and c instances of a and use b and c separately. What went wrong?

Additionally, everything went well when I set up something similar with a function using yield instead of the () based generator a.

Comment: `b` and `c` points to the same generator. You **consume** the generator with the for loop which makes it **empty**, so when asking for the next you got StopIteration error

Comment: @azro Thanks, sounds plausible so far. So if I use a function with yield instead of the () it works because it calls the functions separately each time, generating independent objects, while here I only create "links" to the original object?

Comment: The goal is to create new instance, you don't mandatory need a `yield` https://repl.it/repls/RemoteAdventurousDemoware

Comment: @azro That makes sense, thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

BOTH b and c are pointing to same generator object , while you are looping through generator b , it is consuming elements of c also , so once you consume all elements of b,
and trying to consume it with c i.e by next(c) it is giving you StopIteration error.